# `distinctUntilChanged` how to allow the same item once onNext is called

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an observable which continuously emits items ,and I need to process each one (the process function takes some time). So, meantime while processing an Item, if another item emits with the same value,
I can ignore it, since the same is already in progress. But once the current item is processed (and called onNext). and later if the same request comes, I should allow it.
I used the `distinctUntildChanged` operator, but what I can see is , it will not allow if the current item is same as the last one, even if the last item completed processing and called `onNext`.

I have a sample to demonstrate the issue

I have a class

```
class User {
    String id;
    String name;

    public User(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        User obj1 = (User) obj;
        return id.equals(obj1.id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And an observable (Subject)

```
Subject<User> mSubject = PublishSubject.create();
```

And my Observable chain is

```
 mSubject
.doOnNext(i -> Log.d(TAG, "emitted: " + i))
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.distinctUntilChanged()
.map(user -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "processing " + user);
    Thread.sleep(5000); // processing takes 5 seconds
    return user;
}).subscribe(user -> Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + user.name));
```

And I emit values like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);            
        mSubject.onNext(new User(String.valueOf(1), "User " + i)); // all `User`s have same id
    }
```

The result is

```
emitted: User 0
processing User 0
emitted: User 1
emitted: User 2
emitted: User 3
emitted: User 4
onNext: User 0
emitted: User 5
emitted: User 6
emitted: User 7
emitted: User 8
emitted: User 9
emitted: User 10
emitted: User 11
emitted: User 12
emitted: User 13
emitted: User 14
emitted: User 15
emitted: User 16
emitted: User 17
emitted: User 18
emitted: User 19
```

All the objects are same here (equals method checks id).  As you can see it took `user0` first time, and will take 5 seconds to process, during this time I can ignore incoming items,
but after that `onNext: User 0`  I should allow the same user request, but `distinctUntilChanged` does not allow since its hoding the last value eqal to the same user, How can I do this? 
Hope my question is clear.

Comment: I think you need to use a Flowable with a DROP BackpressureStrategy

Comment: I tried both `BackpressureStrategy.LATEST` and `BackpressureStrategy.DROP` but it after 5 the second, it starts `processing User 1` and also it will process all the items, I need to take only the most recent item. Like after 5th second, I need only the most recent value only, I can skip all previous

Comment: I'm not sure I really understood the problem, as far as I can tell you don't want `distinctUntilChanged` at all, it sounds like a BackpressureStrategy issue. Could you please update your question?

Comment: I need to process every latest incoming user. If same user comes if already one in progress, I can ignore. If the same user comes after the processing of the old same, I should consider it. Hope its clear now?

Comment: Yes it is clear that way, then you should be able to do that with a Flowable

Comment: This is a situation for the search scenario. Where if already I'm querying with the same query, I can ignore. not always

Comment: Can you please answer it?

Comment: Sorry but even though your problem is interesting, I can't actually answer now, if you won't get an answer I will in ~8 hours :)

Comment: Sure. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can achieve this with a `Flowable` and the right `BackpressureStrategy`. The problem is that you are not setting the buffer size when doing `observeOn`. You could try this (Kotlin though):

```
Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .doOnNext { println("emitting $it") }
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false,1)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe {
        println("consuming $it")
        Thread.sleep(500)
    }
```

The output would look like this:

```
emitting 0
consuming 0
emitting 1
emitting 2
emitting 3
emitting 4
emitting 5
consuming 5
emitting 6
emitting 7
emitting 8
emitting 9
emitting 10
consuming 10
emitting 11
emitting 12
emitting 13
emitting 14
```

When you call `observeOn(Scheduler)` the default buffer size for the back-pressure should be 128, if I'm not mistaken.

You can try by changing the buffer size in the sample above to, say, 3. You would get:

```
emitting 0
consuming 0
emitting 1
...
emitting 5
consuming 1
emitting 6
...
emitting 10
consuming 2
emitting 11
...
emitting 15
consuming 15
emitting 16
...
emitting 20
consuming 16
emitting 21
...
```

Comment: Flawless!! exactly what I wanted. Thank you! Also one more query. What does the second parameter `delayError` actually mean? I didn't get it properly from the documentation. Also the buffersize is the number of items it can hold? or memory size in bytes?

Comment: So the doc for `delayError` says "_indicates if the onError notification may not cut ahead of onNext notification on the other side of the scheduling boundary. If true a sequence ending in onError will be replayed in the same order as was received from upstream_" Sorry I'm not sure what it does actually :) The buffer size is the number of items it will hold before applying the BackpressureStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `groupBy()` operator to separate requests by `User`. In each observable, you could arrange to only handle the latest emission.

```
mSubject
  .doOnNext(i -> Log.d(TAG, "emitted: " + i))
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .groupBy( user -> user )
  .flatMap( userObserverable -> userObservable
                                  .onBackpressureDrop()
                                  .map(user -> {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "processing " + user);
                                    Thread.sleep(5000); // processing takes 5 seconds
                                    return user;
                                  })
  .subscribe(user -> Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + user.name));
```

The `groupBy()` operator creates one observable for each user. A new user will have a new observable created for them. Each user will be emitted on its own observable, and the `onBackpressureDrop()` will drop the user if downstream is not accepting emissions.

Comment: Your code showing doesn't compile. `.onBackPressureDrop()` method not available in `userObservable`

Comment: `onBackpressureDrop()` should be spelled with a lower-case "p".

Comment: Still it does't detect. Pls see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrTOk.png). Now I'm running in IntelliJ instead of android studio thats the only difference. I have added the rxJava2 dependency properly. (Its a maven project running in Intellij)

Comment: Hmmm. `GroupedObservable` in RxJava2 does not have back pressure handling, as you would expected. However, `GroupedFlowable` does. That means you have to use `Flowable` instead of `Observable` when constructing your chain.

Comment: Now, I changed the `Subject` with a  `PublishProcessor` , now your code compiles , but result remains the same

Comment: You will have to look at your pipeline to see where objects are getting buffered. For instance `observeOn()` will buffer 128 items, by default. You can add more logging statements, for instance, before and after the `onBackpressureDrop()` operator.